# How do update and redirect to previous page using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a news page in witch comments can be added. If i click a comment i go to a comment page where i can choose to delete the comment. If i delete the comment i want to go back to the news page and refresh the page so that the comments disapears.

I tryed adding this but then the remove function was not reached

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRemoveComment" Text="Ta bort" OnClientClick="JavaScript: window.history.back(1); return false;" />
```

Commentpage.aspx

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRemoveComment" />
```

Commentpage.aspx.cs

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  btnRemoveComment.Click += btnRemoveComment_Click;
}



private void btnRemoveComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CommentFactory.RemoveComment(CurrentPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a button can't apply two events, it's javascript or code-behind. Try to redirect in code-behind and use Ajax for dynamic update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is ok going back and forth between the news page and comments page. Try this

```
private void btnRemoveComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CommentFactory.RemoveComment(CurrentPage);
  Response.Redirect("news.aspx");
}
```